# How to calculate the opacity of smoke present in the image using OpenCV and python

Tags: python, opencv

I want calculate the opacity of a smoke preset in a particular region of the image. i am able to mark the smoke region and the background region. i tried using contrast ratio between the background and foreground.  But it's not yielding any results. Is there any other way to calculate the opacity of the smoke. [image]

Comment: Could you please share your code with us?

Comment: What do you mean by opacity here? if you mean dark colored (black) smoke as 100 % opacity and light colored (gray) as less than 100 % opacity then you can simply use value of the color (i.e. 0 - 255) to calculate opacity